# Is there comprehensive problems to this storyline?

Tags: creature-design, science-fiction, futurology, super-powers

Well im in the process of making a storyline that has too meet these qualifications.

-The story will take place in a  variety of locations on Earth.

-A variety of ethnicity speaking their native language. *closed captions will be available in 5 different languages*

- the audience needs to *easily*  recognize 25% of the content as scientific fact.

  - 50% of content will be scientific fact, yet not known or only briefly informed. So the average viewer might have to question if plausible from a higher source or intelligence to get a defined answer or reference.
- The remaining content will be theory based/seudoscience?/distant future possibility.

  Here is the introduction to my storyline.

  The Sun rises one morning and it was unrecognizable. The Sun transformed into a Pulsar star.The new pulsar emitted extreme amounts of radiation caused by gamma rays.

  The new amounts of radiation caused every human's DNA to mutate.This mutation activated 33 chromosomes that lied dormant in the human DNA unknown to mankind.    No human felt this activation nor noticed a change.Every human on earth thought the world was coming to a end, Strange extreme weather accured killing thousands.Havoc erupted evacuations took place, complete chaos.

This went on for weeks before humanity noticed the Suns transformation has not disrupted or causing death to any life form.No reports of cancer or skin damage had been observed and life went on in celebration.

9 month's later the celebrations halted, Reports in every country stated babies were being born with a copper based blood.Scientist stated The Pulsars gamma rays has to be the cause of  this new mutation. Humanity was split into two types now, The new copper babies did not seem different or showed signs of sickness, in fact, they never got sick at all.

This was the first sign of how different the copper-bloods were. As the copper-bloods matured a new super ability matured also, "Electromagnetic abilities"

What is part of this world is the hardest to imagine?

Comment: This borders idea-generation. Please specify a bit how the human accomplishes this. Not the science stuff, but something like *It converts energy from food to electromagnetic energy and then uses his mind to project it.* Also impose some upper (and possibly lower) limits on it's abilities.

Comment: I thought science said Human wasn't supposed to have that ability. If you already cursed him with magic, why bother with realistic features? Or rather, you shouldn't ask about how a human came to have such ability first?

Comment: @J_F_B_M- I added the content you suggested, can you help me with the structure of my story so it can be eligible on WorldBuilding S.E

Comment: Worldbuilding isn't the place to get story ideas. We are here to help you with **specific problems** that you are facing in **building the world your story is set in**. I honestly don't see how this question can possibly be turned into something that is on-topic here -- the difference between what you have and what would be on topic is just far too large. On-topic, *specific* questions *might* be about how the sun could be turned into a pulsar (not likely to happen, but with appropriate quantities of handwavium...) or how radiation could turn blood to copper-based.

Comment: "in fact, they never got sick at all"  - Why did the celebrations halt?

Comment: @Michael Kjorling-I have provided the content that a moderator has suggested to add. I have edited and restructured the question. I did not spawn related information from past questions.This is not a duplicate in any way shape or form.I have politely asked for editing suggestion to reopen my question.   But why would you post such a  negative comment?

Comment: I don't see any moderator having been involved with this question. (Though I did hold a diamond here myself until only about a week ago, just after the community moderator election.) I also fail to understand how my comment was overly "negative". This question is not marked as a duplicate at all. You asked for help in making this question eligible on Worldbuilding SE, and I described some reasons why, in its current form, your question is not likely to be eligible for reopening. I also offered some examples of questions that might be answerable and on-topic enough to remain open.

Comment: @Michael Kjorling-You pointed out the mistakes but never suggested how to correct them to meet the requirements.

Comment: I offered two specific suggestions for *other* questions that might possibly be useful for you to have answered -- I can't guess what problems you are facing, so those are just that, examples that might possibly be useful -- before I ran out of comment space.

Comment: I have issues with a lot of your ideas. A pulsar causing mutations in DNA overnight? A pulsar not blasting all life off Earth for that matter? No one noticed the sun turned into a pulsar? Honestly the whole thing reads like something written by a 12 year old

Comment: @Evilscary-Can you add a referance that shows these can not happen? Because I can add a reference to show they can. A 12 year old might have trouble seeing fact from fiction.

Comment: A pulsar is a neutron star, which must be over 2 solar masses.  If the sun was replaced by one, it would in essence have gone out, as the luminosity of a tiny pulsar is a small fraction of the sun.  So the world would be dark, and freeze in short order.

Comment: @Oldcat- Ive researched the possibility already which lead me to add a pulsar into my world. Here is a member that collected a great amount of data just on this topic <http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/36534/134>

Answer (score 2):

Looking at animal models.

The electric eel gives 860 volts and 1 amp two milliseconds enough to shock a person but not as much as a stun gun. Scaling that to human sized (cuz why not) they are already as long as a grown man but only weigh 20 kg (44 lb) ish you can do a 2931 volt shock. still cheaper tto buy a stun-gun.

The freshwater elephantfish produces a EM field and uses it as a hunting sense maybe yu could play with that.

Comment: My question has been put on hold for the reasons of off topic.I would appreciate some editing suggestion from anyone willing to help,  My question does not fit the WordBuilding standards.

Comment: @TheVoid perhaps removing your last sentence and replacing with specific questions about your world rather than simply asking us to write your story...

Comment: @colmde- Thanks, When this question is eligible I will use it as a guide line. This story is untold why suppress it?